# Jquery insert row with ajax not putting row in correct order

Tags: jquery

(Due to me not being able to answer some basic questions about 'values' - I have re-worded the objective - to hopefully make getting to the solution easier/clearer)

This HTML is a starting point. When I click on the 'button' of a row, I want to insert a row AFTER that row. The contents of that new row will come from an ajax call, but for THIS question I just need to insert "tom, dick or harry" (depending on what was selected...) in a TR after.

```
<table id="xTable" >

    <thead>
        ...
    </thead>

    <tfoot>
        ...
    </tfoot>

    <tbody>

        <tr>
            <td nowrap class="segment" >
                <div class="btn-group" >
                    <button class="btn btn-default btn-xs dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" > + <span class="caret" ></span></button>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu segmentList" >
                        <option onclick="insRow('tom')" >tom</option>
                        <option onclick="insRow('dick')" >dick</option>
                        <option onclick="insRow('harry')" >harry</option>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <span class="segmentLabel" >BOB</span> 
            </td>
        </tr>


        <tr>
            <td nowrap class="segment" >
                <div class="btn-group" >
                    <button class="btn btn-default btn-xs dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" > + <span class="caret" ></span></button>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu segmentList" >
                        <option onclick="insRow('tom')" >tom</option>
                        <option onclick="insRow('dick')" >dick</option>
                        <option onclick="insRow('harry')" >harry</option>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <span class="segmentLabel" >LISA</span>
            </td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>

</table>
```

Here is the JS I have now - that doesn't work

```
function insRow( i ) {

    var tr = $( this ).parents().closest( 'tr' );       
    $( '#xTable tbody' ).append( '<tr><td>' + i + </td></tr>' ).insertAfter( tr );

};
```

Here's a fiddle... 
https://jsfiddle.net/w95xsd2L/3/

Comment: what is `this`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/w95xsd2L/4/

1. There is a lot going wrong in your setup, one problem is passing along `this` which could be avoided by explicitly supplying it when you call the function via `insRow.call(this, ...)`.
2. Then there's the manner in how you refer to `parents().closest()`, where parents() isn't necessary.
3. You also don't need the `insertAfter` or to do another table lookup, simply apply `after()` to the already found TR, you found with `closest`

JS:

```
function insRow( i ) {

    var $tr = $( this ).closest( 'tr' );
    $tr.after( '<tr><td>' + i + '</td></tr>' );

};
```

Comment: I have never seen this syntax before - it is counter to almost all examples - I appreciate that it works. But shouldn't $(this) be the element that was clicked/slid/focused on??? isn't it implied??? have to pass it and use ".call" seems like a lot of extra typing

Comment: `this` is never safe, due to how it can morph and transition -- it's more difficult for new JS developers to understand the event stack over learning to be explicit when working with `this`.  In this case, we passed it along using the `call()` function.

Comment: Thx BotNet, appreciate it.

Comment: Really since you're working with jQuery, you could easily do all your click-handling in JavaScript, to keep your code in one place -- that would make it easier to manage.  Example `$('option').click(function(){ insRow.call(this, $(this).text()});`  It would enable you to remove all the `onclick` from the options in the HTML and instead keep everything in JS (one source, which is DRYer, and easier to manage)

Comment: I think my issue is that these ROWs are going to be HTML pulled in from AJAX, and the Dropdowns are going to be pulled in from AJAX too.. so I was liiking at the DOM not knowing something existed because it is brought in after page load...etc. I'll play around more with the efficiency one i get it all working. THX

Comment: Ahh -- yes Virtual DOM is your friend.  Possibly consider something like React

Answer (score 0):

So I do not know what `this` is.

```
var tr = $( this ).parents().closest( 'tr' );
```

What that line is doing is getting a list of all of the parents of the item. After that it goes through that list and finds the parents that are tr. So if you have nested tables, it will be doing some weird stuff. You should drop the parents() portions. You should be doing:

```
var tr = $( this ).closest( 'tr' );
```

Now the line that is adding the new row is not actually doing what you think it is.

```
$( '#xTable tbody' ).append( data ).insertAfter( tr );
```

What it is saying is append "data" to the tbody and than append the tbody after the tr.

You should just be doing

```
tr.after(data);
```

or

```
$(data).insertAfter(tr);
```

Comment: Neither of these work... tr.after(data); or $(data).insertAfter(tr);

Comment: Is data a valid TR element? What is "this" like I asked earlier in the comments? I need more details to help you out. My answer assumes `this` is a child element inside of the tr. It assumes `data` is a valid string that contains html for a table row.

Comment: it a good question - and given my limited knowledge, "this" is the UL element that was clicked on... it is a child of a TD (again if i understand it correctly) - I edited the Q to show the HTML that calls the insRow() function.... I hope that helps define what "this" is.

Comment: option in a UL? That seems invalid. So does it find the tr? `console.log(tr)`?but the closest is how you would get it. So what is "data"?  `console.log(data);`